# How can I get rid of the rounded corners on the ListViewItem in a WPF listview?

Tags: wpf, xaml, styling, listviewitem

I have a style that I am applying to the ItemContainerStyle of a Listview. It puts a line across the bottom of the row and sets the height of the row.

However for some reason - each row seems to have rounded corners (as seen in the snapshot attached). When I look at the style in Blend - there are no rounded corners.

How can I get rid of the rounded corners?

```
<Style TargetType="ListViewItem" x:Key="RowStyle">
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,0,1" />
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource ButtonPressedColor}" />
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="40" />
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFF9EDED"/>

            </Style>            

        <ListView x:Name="lvw_FileList" Background="{DynamicResource Watermark}" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource RowStyle}" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource GreyBorderColor}" BorderThickness="3" Margin="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Mode=OneWay}" d:DataContext="{d:DesignData /SampleData/SampleListItems.xaml}" Foreground="{DynamicResource TextColor}">    
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="False">
                    <GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
                        <Style>
                            <Setter Property="UIElement.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                        </Style>
                    </GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>                  
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Picture" CellTemplate="{DynamicResource PictureCell}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Name" CellTemplate="{DynamicResource CompanyNameCell}" />                   
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Action" CellTemplate="{DynamicResource ActionCell}" />
                    <!--<GridViewColumn Header="Delete" Width="50"/>-->
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>            
        </ListView>
```

[image: Rounded Corners on ListViewItems]

Answer (score 0):

Round conrner is because of this line . you have assigned thickness 1 to the bottom

```
<Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,0,1" />
```

change this to

```
 <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,0,0" />
```

Comment: I see - so the underlying template has a border object with a corner radius set - and as soon as I create a border it inherits this property. To fix it then I would need to create a template for ListItemView?

Comment: By default if you can verify the default ListviewItemStyle in the controltemplate  Contentpresenter is wrapped with a Border and Thickness is Inherited using Templatebinding

Comment: if you need a custom rowstyle you can create your own ListviewItem Style

Answer (score 0):

I think this has nothing todo with your Style of the ListView, but with the Style of your GridViewColumn inside the ListView. Because that style is missing.

Could you post your sample data xml?